# Having trouble starting rails server - no luck with googling it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to start the rails server to complete "Learn Ruby on Rails" by Kehoe and keep getting psych errors and have no idea how to troubleshoot.

Here is the output:

```
/Dropbox/workspace/learn-rails$ rails s
/home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 6 column 15 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych.rb:245:in `load'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:60:in `parse'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:56:in `block in raw_configuration'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:56:in `yield'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:56:in `raw_configuration'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:64:in `global_configuration'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:32:in `configuration'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:42:in `each'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:36:in `load'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro.rb:23:in `load'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/rails/railtie.rb:5:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:123:in `initialize'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:171:in `new'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:171:in `instance'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:90:in `inherited'
from /home/mark/Dropbox/workspace/learn-rails/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:LearnRails>'
from /home/mark/Dropbox/workspace/learn-rails/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:8:in `require'
from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you run bundle first?

Comment: Sounds like a problem in the psyche gem where there is an unknown file it is trying to parse. Have you created your Rails application?

Comment: Hello, thanks for both the responses @PatsyIssa.  I have run bundle install and everything installed fine.  

I looked at the psyche gem (which appears to be using the global ruby 2.1.2 instead of the rvm ruby..but i'm not 100% familiar with the file system, so that's just speculation at this point.

Answer (score 2):

[Psych](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html) is a YAML parser and emitter. I guess that either you have a malformed `database.yml` or wrong encoding or something like that.

Comment: Crap! Sorry, Enrico. I was submitting my answer just as your came in :)

Comment: Okay, how would i troubleshoot that? i have looked at the database.yml file and it's the one that was generated..i haven't touched it.  Do i delete the file folder? sorry, still very new to ruby/rails

Comment: @EnricoCarlesso Thanks for your response! I'm trying to troubleshoot this, and looked at my database.yml file, it appears to be the default that was created when the gems were installed.  I would post it but i tried and it said the comment was too long.  

how would i find the problem with the .yml files? i don't want to do a workaround and install syck or anything, but if thats my only option, i'll do it.

Comment: okay, i figured it  out, you guys were right, the secret.yml file had a word that was not commented out.  i fixed it, but how did you guys know that it was in the config/ directory?

Comment: Because must (all) YAML file are there :-)

Answer (score 2):

Given that `Psych` is a gem for handling YAML files and that your error indicates a syntax error, the odds are pretty solid you have a malformed YAML file somewhere in your `config/` directory.

Comment: I guess you win by 4 seconds :)

Comment: It was a photo finish LOL!